# Use cookie to set link?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, location-href

If cookies are used to stor simple strings can I also use the cookie to set the link of a button.

the idea: I have a simple HTML which i use to create a help file (this is very simple and I already have it), but we also make use of heaps of relating MSDS documents, so instead of me finding the thousands of documents online, i was thinking that Id get my users to set this by setting a cookie and ussing the cookies string to set the   link ready for use the next time?

I can set read delete and modyfy cookies using Javascript...

Comment: It seems you're all done. What's the issue?

Comment: I dont know how to use\ configure the HTML button to open the link stored in the cookie..

Answer (score 0):

Granted this function (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) to get the cookie item works, this should do the job:

```
var getCookie = function(cname)
{
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
    {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name)==0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

var click = function () {
    window.location.href = getCookie('buttonUrl');
}

<button onclick="click()">See documentation</button>
```

Comment: that sorta dose the trick however my adressbar now includes the cookies original html page location.. example when prompted for a cookie and i type www.example.com, and then proceed to click my button my adress bar trys to open C:\desktop\www.example.com and not www.example.com as would be requierd for succcess?